# Keepass key file format

Tags: format, keepass, key-file

Using Keepass XC complains about my kee file format:

```
You are using a legacy key file format which may become
unsupported in the future.

Please consider generating a new key file.
```

How do I update the key file format?

Preferably in a way that I do only change the format not the key itself. (Else I have to transfer the key to all devices again.

Comment: But you'll have to transfer the reformatted key to all devices anyway.

Comment: OK Good point. But can you give link or description of the new format?

Answer (score 1):

There's a brief explanation of what keyfiles are supported in a docstring [in the Keepass XC source](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/master/src/keys/FileKey.cpp#L35):

```
 * Read key file from device while trying to detect its file format.
 *
 * If no legacy key file format was detected, the SHA-256 hash of the
 * key file will be used, allowing usage of arbitrary files as key files.
 * In case of a detected legacy key file format, the raw byte contents
 * will be extracted from the file.
 *
 * Supported legacy formats are:
 *  - KeePass 2 XML key file
 *  - Fixed 32 byte binary
 *  - Fixed 32 byte ASCII hex-encoded binary
 *
 * Usage of legacy formats is discouraged and support for them may be
 * removed in a future version.
```

This matches [the Keepass docs](https://keepass.info/help/base/keys.html#keyfiles), stating that a key can be any arbitrary file:

```
File Type and Existing Files. KeePass can generate key files for you, however you can also use any other, already existing file (like JPG image, DOC document, etc.).
```

Keepass XC unfortunately doesn't explicitly state what key formats are supported (at least that I could find), but the code seems to imply that **a supported keyfile is any arbitrary file that isn't in a legacy format**.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info.
That indicates that it is not possible to change just the format
(Else the hash algorithm would be considered as broken)

Comment: No prob! Sorry that it can't be converted to a new format without rekeying entirely. You can change the key to a new key under database settings though if you need. :) @ThorstenNiehues